# Is it possible to download all cordova plugins from dependency file

Tags: cordova, dependencies, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

Is there any solution for problem from the topic?

What I mean is to have a file like in bower - bower.json where we have all project dependencies. Files are added to git ignore and everyone can install dependencies using bower install.

In cordova, in plugins filder, I see android.json file. Is there possibility not to commit all plugins, just android.json, then use a command to download them?

Thanks

Comment: You can look into setting up a 'hook' that adds all the plugins specified in a given file. I have mine to run after `cordova platform add` (http://devgirl.org/2013/11/12/three-hooks-your-cordovaphonegap-project-needs/)